# PoE Design Question

Tags: dc-dc-converter, isolation, poe

I am working on a PoE project that calls for a power to be supplied to a application circuit. The application circuit requires ~41W (24V, 1.7A). I am exploring using [PD70201](https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/poe-pd-front-end-w-pwm-controller/4784-pd70201#resources) as the PD controller. The PD70201 + isolation DC/DC circuit outputs 12V 4A on Vout+. In order to use this part, I assume on the application circuit I'll have to use a DC/DC converter such as [S24SP24002PDFA](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/delta-electronics/S24SP24002PDFA/941-1757-ND/6133826) to convert the 12V 4A to 24V 1.7A for the application circuit power needs. Is this correct? Also the DC/DC converter is a bit expensive at $46.35/chip. Can the isolation DC/DC circuit be modified so a cheaper DC/DC converter can be used? Or modified so the isolation DC/DC circuit just outputs 24V 1.7A?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to modify the circuit so that it outputs 24V, but when you use 1.7 A at that voltage, you draw more power than the original circuit could supply. The resulting design changes would therefore affect quite a few of the components. This is going to be nontrivial. See if you can find design information in data sheets and/or application notes for the chip.

Comment: No you cannot get 24Vx1.7A in power from a 24W supply

Comment: It is impossible to convert 12V, 2A to 24V, 1.7A. You can't get more power out than the power in.

Comment: @sh- the evaluation board and documentation says the isolation DC/DC circuit should output 12V, 4A (48W). Made the modification to the description.

Comment: @be-ee: OK, so at least you stay within the same power rating. Then, at the very least, you would need a different flyback transformer with a different turns ratio (T1), and a different voltage divider ratio for the voltage feedback (R10). Very likely further component changes are required, but I'm not going to do the design work for you.